# Function that return current URL with completion Handler

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler, share-extension

I have a `ShareExtension` in which I like need to get the `current URL`. This is my function for it:

```
var html: String?

    if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem,
        let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first,
        itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
        itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil) { (url, error) in
            if (url as? URL) != nil {
                html = (self.getHTMLfromURL(url: url as? URL))
            }

        }
    }
```

My problem is that I need the `html` but when using that `variable` right after that function `html` is still empty. I think I need some sort of `completion handler` but I tried different things now and can not get it right...

This is how my whole function looks like at the moment (not working, as `html` becomes an empty `String`)

```
@objc func actionButtonTapped(){

    do {

        var html: String?

        if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem,
            let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first,
            itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil) { (url, error) in
                if (url as? URL) != nil {
                    html = (self.getHTMLfromURL(url: url as? URL))
                }

            }
        }


        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html ?? "")

        let priceClasses: Elements = try doc.select("[class~=(?i)price]")

        for priceClass: Element in priceClasses.array() {
            let priceText : String = try priceClass.text()
            print(try priceClass.className())
            print("pricetext: \(priceText)")
        }

        let srcs: Elements = try doc.select("img[src]")
        let srcsStringArray: [String?] = srcs.array().map { try? $0.attr("src").description }

        for imageName in srcsStringArray {
            print(imageName!)
        }

    } catch Exception.Error( _, let message) {
        print(message)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }

}
```

The **Goal** is to have a extra `function` to get the `url` (1st code example) with a completion handler in which I can work with the created `html`.

Comment: Which variable is `nil` when you find `html` in the first code example? Is `html` not `nil` when you check `html` later, or does it remain `nil`?

Comment: @Daniel `doc` becomes `""`  because `html` is still nill

Comment: I meant: is `extensionContext==nil` or `extensionContext?.inputItems.first==nil`, etc. in the first block of code that you posted?

Comment: @Daniel oh sorry. No it is not. When I call `print ((self.getHTMLfromURL(url: url as? URL))` , the HTML gets printed

Comment: But it is asynchronous so I need some sort of completion handling

Comment: Ah I see. Do you already have code for `getHTMLFromURL(url:)` or is it just a placeholder?

Comment: I already have the code and it is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212630/discussion-between-chris-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that I didn't realize that I already had a `completionHandler`  with `loadItems`. So what I did now was to put the whole `do & catch` block in another method and called it in the completion handler like this:

```
@objc func actionButtonTapped(){

        var html: String?

        if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem,
            let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first,
            itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil) { (url, error) in
                if (url as? URL) != nil {
                    html = (self.getHTMLfromURL(url: url as? URL))
                    print("bruh")

                    self.doStuff(html: html)
                }
            }
        }
}

func doStuff(html: String?){
    do {
        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html ?? "")

        let priceClasses: Elements? = try doc.select("[class~=(?i)price]")

            for priceClass: Element in priceClasses!.array() {
            let priceText : String = try priceClass.text()
            print(try priceClass.className())
            print("pricetext: \(priceText)")
        }

        let srcs: Elements = try doc.select("img[src]")
        let srcsStringArray: [String?] = srcs.array().map { try? $0.attr("src").description }

        for imageName in srcsStringArray {
            print(imageName!)
        }

            } catch Exception.Error( _, let message) {
                print(message)
            } catch {
                print("error")

        }
}
```